# Excel : Display Column name from another sheet if its written as 'Y'

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, xlookup

I am trying to modify this.
Sheet 1 has`Name` and `category` column and sheet 2 has `Name` and `category names as column`
i want to display as following way i tried `Vlookup` and `match` however no luck.

[image: Output should be like this]

[image: Another sheet from where have to match values]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try-

```
=INDEX($G$3:$J$3,1,MATCH("y",INDEX(TRANSPOSE($G$4:$J$8),,MATCH(A2,$F$4:$F$8,0)),0))
```

> Edit: See below updated formula

```
=FILTER($G$3:$J$3,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS($G$4:$J$8),1,0),($G$4:$J$8="y")*($F$4:$F$8=A2)))
```

If you want to show result in same cell by comma separated then try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, FILTER($G$3:$J$3,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS($G$4:$J$8),1,0),($G$4:$J$8="y")*($F$4:$F$8=A2))))
```

[image]

Comment: if there is more then one category per name ?

Comment: i want both of them for ex. ` name a has prod and service` i want both of them instead of only `prod or service`

Comment: Result will show in same cell or different cells?

Comment: different cell , it doesnt matter tho

Comment: there should be all resulets, in some cases name is associated with all categories or in some associated with 0 categories